# Windows Azure Tools: Error: Unable to find nativerd.dll

Tags: iis, azure

I am using VS2010 for a simple Windows Azure project, When I run the project I get error

following error

Windows Azure Tools: Error: IIS is not installed
Windows Azure Tools: Error: Unable to find nativerd.dll. Please verify that IIS is installed properly.
Windows Azure Tools: The system is missing a prerequisite to execute the service. Please see the release notes.

I have IIS 8 Express installed already, what else should I install to get rid of this error? Also installed VS2010SP1AzurePack.2E2.2E1

Any help would be much appriciated.

Regards,
Mansoor.

Answer (score 4):

Turned out that IIS feature was not enabled in Windows Features...! 
It worked after I enabled it.

Comment: What feature needed to be enabled?

Comment: In your config panel of Windows, you have a "active windows features" link or something, under which you can check IIS.